# C# code generator referenced assembly is not run

Tags: c#, code-generation

I have a problem using source code generators. The actual code generation works fine - as long as I reference the generator as .csproj.

Repository with code: https://github.com/Sigurdur42/EasyI18n

Setup: The generator shall generate code for localizable messages.
There are 2 solutions in the repository:

- EasyI18n/EasyI18N.sln: Contains the generator and unit tests consuming the generator csproj
- EasyI18n.PackageConsumer/EasyI18nPackageConsumer/EasyI18nPackageConsumer.sln: Contains a consumer which references the generator as assembly and one which references the locally build nuget package

No analyzer is used in the EasyI18nPackageConsumer.sln. Not even the one where I just reference the assembly and set the required properties manually:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EasyI18N.Generator" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\nugetPackages\EasyI18N.Generator.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The working test is in the solution EasyI18N in EasyI18N.Tests:
The class `SimpleGetMessageTest` contains this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SimpleGetMessageTest
{
    public void EnsureMessageTest()
    {
        var easyI18n = new EasyI18NContainer("de");
        var localizedMessage = easyI18n.GetTestMessage();
        Assert.That(localizedMessage, Is.EqualTo("Testnachricht"));
    }
}
```

The method `GetTestMessage` is generated via analyser from `LocalizeTestData.xml`.

The consumer project has this code:

```
using EasyI18n;

namespace EasyI18nAssemblyConsumer
{
    public class LanguageConsumer
    {
        public LanguageConsumer(IEasyI18N easyI18N)
        {
            // This project consumes the dll 
            // The analyzer is not run..

            var localizedMessage = easyI18N.GetTestMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the `GetTestMessage` cannot be found - if I check VS analyser for that project, I do not see the EasyI18n one :(

Any help or hint is apprechiated.

Comment: have you registered this in DI in your program.cs or start up?  your test works because you are initialising a new instance, but when you run it, how are you initialising it? Is this through DI, or do you need to new it up before you call `LanguageConsumer`?

Comment: @SimonPrice This is just sample code - there is no DI yet. It actually fails the compilation, not at runtime. Therefore the question is not relevant for the issue :)
But you can just initialize a new instance of the EasyI18nContainer and pass it to the consumer if you like.